# When 'action'/'runInAction' is really needed in mobx react

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

Can someone explain to me what is the real difference and why both of the example here are working the same:

1) Change a state of observable via action/runInAction inside the store file:

colorStore file:

```
@observable
color='red'

@action
setColor(){
  this.color='blue'
}
```

2)Change the state via the component itself (which assumed to be bad practice):

React Component file:

```
onClick = () => this.props.colorStore.color='blue' //still working...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mobx `action` is doing the **batching**, similarly to how ReactJS batches multiple changes.

When you use reactjs `click` handler react is automatically batching changes that happen inside it, so you will not see component rendering multiple times, however, if you call `setColor` from some other event, let's say after loading some data, and have multiple calls to change the observable inside the `setColor` that will trigger the observer three times, and the component will be rendered three times.

When you wrap your function with  `@action` decorator or you use `runInAction` function, only the last value will be used (`green` in the code below) and the component will be rendered only once.

```js
setColor(){
  // this will render three times
  this.color='blue'
  this.color='red'
  this.color='green'
}
```

vanilla mobx example that reacts only once:

```js
import { runInAction, observable, reaction, toJS } from "mobx";

const test = observable({
  name: "sonic",
  nick: "speed demon"
});

// console.log will be called only once with the value "name: 3"
reaction(
  () => toJS(test),
  data => console.log(`name: ${data.name}`)
);

runInAction(() => {
  test.name = "1";
  test.name = "2";
  test.name = "3";
});
```

view on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-wildflower-tzg5e)

Also check out the discussion on the github repo: [is @action really necessary?](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react/issues/505)

Answer (score 0):

The difference is more related to **conventions** and writing **clean maintainable code** than in the behavior of the program. So:

1. You are **mutating** store data in your **UI** component. This is not correct, because the **UI** should only **visualize** data and handle for example user actions which are then translated to certain action in the data store(in your case updating a color). It's **store responsibility** to manage the **state** of this data
2. All **observable** data is considered a good practice to be **mutated** only in **actions**. Why? Because the single source of mutating data is clear - only in actions and only in a data layer(the store). The code is less prone to errors and unclear state management and the great benefit is that you can enforce your application not to build if you turn on `use strict` mode